Equilibria of non-linear system with infinite number of non-isolated critical points
I have the following non-linear system:
$$
x'=x^2-y^2\\
y'=x-y
$$
I am trying to investigate the stability and equilibria. Systematically, we should be able to linearize this system and then investigate the equilibria at the critical points by looking at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian, provided the eigenvalues are not pure imaginary (a center). The Jacobian is
$$
J(x,y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
2x && -2y\\
1 && -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Intuitively, the critical points for this system are all real numbers such that $y_0=x_0$. So, this suggests that this system has infinitely many non-isolated critical points. Further, for critical points $y_0=x_0$, the Jacobian $J(x_0,y_0)$ is singular (i.e., $\text{det}(J)=0$). I believe that the fact that we have a line of non-isolated critical points falls out of the fact that the Jacobian is singular.
According to a theorem by Poincaré, if $(x_0,y_0)$ is an isolated critical point of a non-linear system and $J(x_0,y_0)$ is the Jacobian of the linearization, then the equilibria of $(x_0,y_0)$ should mirror that of the origin (0,0), with the nature of the equilibria depending of the eigenvalues of the Jacobian (i.e., depending on whether the eigenvalues are real and have the same sign, real with opposite signs, or complex but not pure imaginary). However, in order for this to be useful, $\text{det}(J)\neq0$.
So, how can we understand the equilibria when the system contains a line of non-isolated critical points?

The eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix are $0$ and $2x_0-1$ at the equilibrium point $(x_0,x_0)$. Therefore, for $x_0>1/2$, the equilibrium is unstable, whereas for $x_0<1/2$, it is stable.

@Pranay You are half right. For $x_0\le 1/2$ we can coclude nothing from the Jacobian.

The solutions can be visualized as a stream plot. That makes the change in behavior at $x_0=1/2$ visually evident.

@AVK. I don’t follow. Why can’t we conclude anything from the Jacobian for $x_0\le 1/2$? The stream plot in Semiclassical’s comment confirms my answer.

@Pranay Because the system is nonlinear. $\lambda_1<0$,  $\lambda_2=0$ is the so-called critical case, when stability of the linearized system may not coincide with the stability of the original system

@AVK. Can you please give me an example where they don’t agree?

@Pranay $\dot x= -x$, $\dot y= y^2$

@AVK. Thanks! That makes sense!

Any system with a common factor on the right side is a speed change away from the system without the factor. So the trajectories of the given system are geometrically (almost) the same as the ones of $\dot x=x+y$, $\dot y=1$ with special attention to be given to the line $x-y=0$.

This particular system can be solved simply by finding its first integral:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-y^2,\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=x-y\quad\Rightarrow\quad 
dt=\frac{dx}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{dy}{x-y}
\quad (x\ne y);
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=x-y \quad\Rightarrow\quad (x+y+1)e^{-y}=C.
$$
So, the trajectories of the system (except for the line $x=y$) lie on the curves $(x+y+1)e^{-y}=C$:

It remains to determine the direction in which the movement along the curves occurs. This can be done by calculating the derivative along the trajectories of the system of the function $v(x,y)=x-y$:
$$
\dot v= \frac{d}{dt}(x-y)=\dot x-\dot y= x^2-y^2-x+y.
$$
If $v>0$ and $\dot v<0$, then the movement occurs towards line $x-y=0$,
if $v>0$ and $\dot v>0$ then away from the line etc. We have
$$
\dot v=0  \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x-y=0 \vee x+y=1,
$$
so the picture is as follows

